# Which Macs cannot upgrade to Mountain Lion?

Tags: compatibility, macos

As everyone already know, Mountain Lion was released today. I am eager to get my Mac ready for Mountain Lion, but I know that a number of Macs do not support Mountain Lion. Is there a list of Macs that *won’t* support OS X Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple [said](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/) the following Macs *will* run Mountain Lion:

- iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
- MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
- MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

So the complement of this list are *not* supported to run Mountain Lion (as far as I can tell; edit this list to add or subtract models as appropriate; you may be able to get it running on an unsupported machine):

- Macintosh 128K
- Macintosh 512K
- Macintosh 128K (revised)
- Macintosh XL
- Macintosh Plus
- Macintosh 512Ke
- Macintosh Plus (Platinum)
- Macintosh SE
- Macintosh II
- Macintosh IIx
- Macintosh SE/30
- Macintosh IIcx
- Macintosh SE FDHD
- Macintosh IIci
- Macintosh Portable
- Macintosh IIfx
- Macintosh LC
- Macintosh Classic
- Macintosh IIsi
- Macintosh Portable (backlit screen)
- Macintosh Classic II
- Quadra 700
- Quadra 900
- PowerBook 100
- PowerBook 140
- PowerBook 170
- Macintosh LC II
- Quadra 950
- PowerBook 145
- Macintosh IIvi
- Macintosh IIvx
- PowerBook 160
- PowerBook 180
- PowerBook Duo 210
- PowerBook Duo 230
- Macintosh LC III / III+
- Macintosh Color Classic
- Centris 610
- Centris 650
- Quadra 800
- PowerBook 165c
- Workgroup Server 80
- Workgroup Server 95
- PowerBook 145b
- PowerBook 180c
- Macintosh LC 520
- Workgroup Server 60
- Centris / Quadra 660AV
- Quadra 840AV
- PowerBook 165
- Macintosh Color Classic II
- Macintosh TV
- Quadra 605
- Quadra 610
- Quadra 650
- PowerBook Duo 250
- PowerBook Duo 270c
- Macintosh LC 550
- Macintosh LC 575
- Power Macintosh 6100
- Power Macintosh 7100
- Power Macintosh 8100
- Workgroup Server 6150
- Workgroup Server 8150
- Workgroup Server 9150
- PowerBook 520/c
- PowerBook 540/c
- PowerBook 550
- PowerBook Duo 280
- PowerBook Duo 280c
- Quadra 630
- PowerBook 150
- Power Macintosh 6200 / 6300
- Macintosh LC 580
- Performa 5200
- Power Macintosh 9500
- Power Macintosh 7200
- Power Macintosh 7500
- Power Macintosh 8500
- PowerBook 190
- PowerBook 5300
- PowerBook Duo 2300c
- Workgroup Server 7250
- Workgroup Server 8550
- Performa 5260 / 5300
- Performa 5400
- Power Macintosh 7600
- Performa 6360
- Performa 6400
- Power Macintosh 4400
- PowerBook 1400
- Power Macintosh 5500
- Power Macintosh 6500
- Power Macintosh 7300
- Power Macintosh 8600
- Power Macintosh 9600
- PowerBook 3400
- Twentieth Anniversary Macintosh
- Workgroup Server 7350
- Workgroup Server 9650
- PowerBook 2400c
- Power Macintosh G3 desktop
- Power Macintosh G3 minitower
- PowerBook G3
- Power Macintosh G3 AIO
- Macintosh Server G3
- PowerBook G3 series
- iMac G3
- Power Macintosh G3 (Blue & White)
- Macintosh Server G3 (Blue & White)
- PowerBook G3 ("Lombard")
- iBook
- Macintosh Server G4
- iMac (slot loading)
- Power Mac G4 Graphite
- PowerBook ("Pismo")
- Power Mac G4 Cube
- iBook (FireWire)
- PowerBook G4 Titanium
- iBook (white)
- Power Mac G4 Quicksilver
- Server G4 Quicksilver
- iMac G4 15"
- iBook (14")
- eMac
- Xserve
- iMac G4 17"
- Power Mac G4 MDD
- Macintosh Server G4 MDD
- PowerBook G4 Aluminum (12")
- PowerBook G4 Aluminum (17")
- Xserve slot loading
- Xserve Cluster Node
- Power Mac G5
- PowerBook G4 Aluminum (15")
- iBook G4 (12" / 14")
- iMac G4 20"
- Xserve G5
- Xserve Cluster Node G5    Xserve
- Power Mac G5 FX
- iMac G5 17"
- iMac G5 20"   iMac
- Mac mini
- Power Mac G5 dual core
- iMac Core Duo
- MacBook Pro (15")
- Mac mini Core Solo
- Mac mini Core Duo
- MacBook Pro (17")
- MacBook   (Late 2008 plastic)
- Xserve (Intel) (Late 2006)
- MacBook (Late 2006)
- Mac mini Core 2 Duo
- MacBook (Late 2007)
- Xserve Harpertown
- MacBook Penryn
- 1st generation MacBook Air  (early 2008)

Comment: Jamie Cruickshank managed to [install Mountain Lion on a Mac Pro 1.1](http://www.j4mie.co.uk/blog/how-to-install-mountain-lion-on-macpro11/)

Comment: 1st gen MBA (Jan 2008) isn't compatible.

Comment: Can we have this list in hardware identifiers, like iMac 9,1 etc? ;)

Comment: See also this attempt at installing it on a Mac Pro 1,1 http://www.jabbawok.net/?p=47